# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(a_n+b_n)}^{-\frac{1}{2n}} = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ are two sequences of positive real numbers such that  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {a_n}^{-\frac{1}{2n}} = \infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {b_n}^{-\frac{1}{2n}} =  \infty$ then is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(a_n+b_n)}^{-\frac{1}{2n}} = \infty$ ?

I am trying this real-analysis problem but cannot progress because I can't see how to use some useful inequalities. Can someone please help?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, ok I'll mention that.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Please note the negative exponent.

Comment: @ThomasAhle Please note the negative exponent.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Note that the example you considered with $a_n=b_n=1$ diverges because $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{-\frac{1}{2n}}=1$ .

Comment: Thanks, Actually I deleted the answer two minutes before you posted this...

Comment: It's true if $a_n=b_n$. Also if $a_nb_n=0$ for all $n$, sort of the other extreme, extremely unequal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true.  Define $a_{2n+1}=b_{2n}=2^{n^2}$ and $a_{2n}=b_{2n+1}=1$.

Comment: I get that the both the individual series diverge. Can you please be a bit explicit about the convergence?

Comment: My mistake, it needed some more $n$ in the exponent.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich isn't the current answer ok with $2^{n^2}$ ?

Comment: @Brozovic Thanks, I hadn't noticed the change.